# Azure Custom Script to restore database from Blob Storage to Managed Instance

Tags: sql, azure, ssms, azure-sql-managed-instance

I need a post VM deployment script in PS to restore a .BAK file located in a Blob Storage to an Azure Managed Instance. I can manually do it manually using SMSS but I get the following error when trying to restore the file from a SQL query (image of error in link below because I do not have enough rep to post images)

Query I'm actually running:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL blobstorage
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = '$StrgAccSAS';

RESTORE DATABASE [$DBName] 
FROM URL = '$URL'
WITH CREDENTIAL 'blobstorage';
```

The requested parameters are correctly passed when executing the script.

[Restore error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXNvl.png)

Answer (score 1):

When [creating a credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with the `SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE` you *must*:

- name the credential the same as the container path
- it must start with https
- it cannot contain a trailing forward slash

Once you've done that, you do NOT (and can not in Managed Instances) use the `WITH CREDENTIAL` option.  SQL will use the credential you set up that matches the URL you're restoring from:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [$DBName] 
FROM URL = '$URL'
```